# How to get t and p-value in two sample t-test on two means, but the hypothesis is the mean of both have difference of a particular number?

Tags: python, scipy, t-test

I have two dataframes of samples both are from different populations (`df1` and `df2`)

I am trying to get the t and p-value. Here's what I have done:

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats as stats
        stats.ttest_ind(a=df1, b=df2)
Out [1]: Ttest_indResult(statistic=-2.071536903102, pvalue=0.0385310564401)
```

---

What this input produce are the t and p-value for the null hypothesis:  [image: null_hypothesis_1].

**In contrast**, what I am trying to do is to get the t and p-value for the null hypothesis that there is a particular means difference which is a particular number, for instance, `0.3`, [image: null_hypothesis_2]

Is there any function in any library that can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the hypothesis that the two data frames are the same distribution except that the means are different by `0.3`, just subtract `0.3` off of `df1`. Then you can use the standard `stats.ttest_ind` function you used previously.